# Как в цикле foreach выводить значения по возрастанию key?

Tags: php

Хочу выводить сначала все значения value2 у которых одинаковый key.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
                    echo ' value — ' . $value2 . ' key — ' . $key2 . '<br>';
    }
}
```

$_POST вида:

```
    Array
    (
        [username] => Array
            (
                [0] => Саша
                [1] => Иван
            )

        [surname] => Array
            (
                [0] => Иванов
                [1] => Александров
            )
)
```

Сейчас это выводит

> value — Саша key — 0 
>  value — Иван key — 1 
>  value — Иванов key
>   — 0 
>  value — Александров key — 1

Как я хочу:

> value — Саша key — 0 
>  value — Иванов key
>   — 0 
>  value — Иван key — 1 
>  value — Александров key — 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Получаете текущий массив массива *$_POST* в переменную *$value*
2. Извлекаете из *$value* первый элемент и выводите его в браузер
3. Если в переменной *$value* остались значения, повторить п.1-п.2

---

```
$_POST = [
    'username' => [
        'Саша',
        'Иван'
    ],

    'surname' => [
        'Иванов',
        'Александров'
    ]
];

do {
    foreach ($_POST as &$value) {
        echo array_shift($value) . "\n";
    }
} while (! empty($value));
```

См. [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/761485862a3c0c4c9b7675c91a394d61b65b01e0)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_POST['username'] as $key => $value) {
    echo ' value — ' . $value . ' key — ' . $key . '<br>';
    echo ' value — ' . $_POST['surname'][$key] . ' key — ' . $key . '<br>';
}
```